# how can i center the footer text in the bottom of the page regardless of screen size

Tags: html, css

This is my html codes, i am having a hard time center the email on the bottom of the page. so how can i center the footer text in the bottom of the page regardless of screen size

```
    <body>
        <div class = 'container' >
                <header> ****** Illustration</header>





        </div>

        <!-- Sign and date the page, it's only polite! -->
        <footer> <a href="mailto:*******@cmail.carleton.ca">
    *******@cmail.carleton.ca</a></footer>

    </body>
```

this is my css code, I tried centering the footer to be on the center bottom of the page, but every time i use a different screen size the location of the text change, how can i avoid this issue??

```
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="dist/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

.container {
    width : 900px;
    margin : 0 auto;
  }

 body {
    background :    url('images/black_background.jpg');
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    possition: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0:
    z-index: -5000;
    overflow-x:hidden


    }

header{
    min-width:  900px;
    height: 90px;
    background: url('images/header.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat;
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
    color:  white;
    position: relative;
    right: -85x;
    color:          white;
    font-size:      3em;
    font-family:    Lucida Handwriting;


    }

nav{
    width:  900px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color:  white;
    background: url();
    position: relative;
    right: 250px;
    top: -40px;
    height: 90px;
    min-width: 900px;

    }

/*#content{
    width: 900px;
    height: 650px;
    position: relative;
    left:   -45px;
    background:url('images/himba_tribes.jpg');

    }
    */

footer{
     position:absolute;
    bottom:-40;
    width:100%;
    height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
    background:#6cf;
    border: 4px solid orange;
    clear: both;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
Make the footer a div:
`<div id="footer">your@email</div>`

And the CSS should be:
`#footer { clear: both; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center}`

Comment: thank you, this work but i want it as a link, because it an email address

Comment: href will make it an email link `<div id="footer"><a href="mailto:your@email.com">your@email</a></div>`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to center the Link horizontally, use `text-align: center;` on the footer. If you want to make it stick to the bottom of the window, use a [Sticky Footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/)!